# AngularJS wrong unix time parse result

Tags: javascript, unix, angularjs, timestamp

I have a timestamp `1378028575` that gives me `Sun, 01 Sep 2013 09:42:55 GMT` [here](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm). But when I try to format it with Angular `date`, it returns it as `Jan 17, 1970 2:47:08 AM`, using this format: `{{'1378028575' | date:'medium'}}`. The result from the site is correct but in Angular is wrong. Why does it happen, or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Date is Javascript is milliseconds from Epoch. You have used seconds. Try 1378028575*1000

Answer (score 19):

Its cause you use seconds not milliseconds.

```
new Date(1378028575)
Fri Jan 16 1970 23:47:08 GMT+0100 (CET)

new Date(1378028575000)
Sun Sep 01 2013 11:42:55 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

from the angular docs:

> Date to format either as Date object, milliseconds (string or number)
>   or various ISO 8601 datetime string formats (e.g.
>   yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ and its shorter versions like
>   yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ, yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ). If no timezone is
>   specified in the string input, the time is considered to be in the
>   local timezone.

Comment: Then seems like the answer given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925020/angularjs-convert-tag-value-unix-time-to-human-readable-time is not correct? They talk about unix time there and seems like the OP will have the same issues.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I'm using Stripe, and it returns all times as seconds rather than milliseconds. Multiplying every date by 1000 did the trick!

Answer (score 13):

The other answer isnt quite complete. Since your timestamp is in seconds, not miliseconds, in Angular.js you can do this:

```
{{1378028575 * 1000 | date:'medium'}}
```

Knowing seconds * 1000 = miliseconds is one thing. Knowing you can put math in the date expression is another :)

Comment: This is likely the better answer for most people goggling this. I was trying to decided where to address this after reading the initial answer. Ideally, I would have liked to address this in my service but it returns a promise. This left me with the controller, but if another controller ever uses this service I would have to repeat the code or make a helper functions. Then I read your answer. Ideally the service would be the place to handle this but I'm not sure it is possible with a complete rewrite.