# Conversion of Date from .Net to Angularjs

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, angularjs

when passing an object which contains a date from C# to AngularJS
the value of the date appears as "/Date(1408482000000)/" and not as a valid date.

my angular code:

```
$scope.GetLastCompletedAction = function () {
       $http.post('Default.aspx/GetLastCompletedAction', {}).success(function (data,    status, headers, config) {
        $scope.objects = JSON.parse(data.d);
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.status = status;
        console.log(status);
    });
}
```

objects is a list of objects.
every object contains a field named startDate which appears invalid.

thanks,
Nadav

Comment: Did you try converting the date object in C# to timestamp? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa
and you can convert date back from the timestamp value to date in angular js http://stackoverflow.com/a/17925117/1904479

Comment: That *is* a valid JSON date format (one of several). What's going wrong?

Comment: Reffer to this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date,

Comment: i didn't try to convert the date object to timestamp, it is being converted (serialized) as a DateTime object.
and when the date appears as "/Date(1408482000000)/" and i am trying to use inside a ng-repeat {{date | date : shortDate}} the operation doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a funcion like this

```
$scope.formatDate = function (jsonDate)
{
    var milli = jsonDate.replace(/\/Date\((-?\d+)\)\//, '$1');
    var date = new Date(parseInt(milli));
    return date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before and it is the `Date` object in javascript that does not consider that date valid.

If you pass to the `Date` constructor only the number which is inside `/Date(*)/`, you will see it will work. It did for me.

Hope I helped :)

Comment: I know about this solution but it isn't good enough for me, i need to be able to use the date inside a ng-repeat with angular.

Comment: @NadavStern if you don't want to convert at server you can create custom filter and use angular date filter to format data inside the custom filter

Comment: When you do your post to `GetLastCompletedAction`, right after you parse, why don't you change all the dates objects and take only what is inside `/Date(*)/`? That way you can use it in angular and it is a valid `Date` object.