# AngularJS UnixTime to DateTime Format with date filter failed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, unix-timestamp, angular-filters

I learned that one can transform a unix time stamp into a date by using date filter from this post:
[AngularJS. Convert tag value (Unix time to human-readable time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925020/angularjs-convert-tag-value-unix-time-to-human-readable-time)

But I can not convert mine with it...

```
<td>{{contract.start_date_unix | date:'MM-dd-yyyy'}}</td>
```

inside the `contract.start_date_unix`, its valued at `1406779200`

I checked it with a [checker](http://www.epochconverter.com/) that it shows exactly what I want:
Thu, 31 Jul 2014 04:00:00 GMT **(but of course, the format I want is MM-dd-yyyy, the date is correct and that's what I try to prove here)**

But when I do the date filter above, it will only show `01-17-1970` or `01-16-1970`...

What could be the issue cause this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

the time shown is epoch and not actual date. please read the links in your question, answer is there in one of the links.

you need to multiply the time by 1000.

```
<td>{{contract.start_date_unix * 1000 | date:'MM-dd-yyyy'}}</td>
```