# Time shown incorrectly from Angular

Tags: angularjs, json, unix, time

Usually code like as:

### html

```
 <p class="small-grey-text float-left">
     {{ product.date-created |  date:'MMMM dd, yyyy ' }} 
 </p>
```

### **json**

```
[{"date-created": 1475798400 }]
```

This is must look as **October 07, 2016**

### Result

January 01, 1970

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS UnixTime to DateTime Format with date filter failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534721/angularjs-unixtime-to-datetime-format-with-date-filter-failed)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are having the same problem as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534721/angularjs-unixtime-to-datetime-format-with-date-filter-failed) thread. The date pipe format is correct you need to multiply out the date by 1000.

Comment: Result: "null". What is this?

Answer (score 0):

> **date-created** or **dateCreated** is word of element for JS.

Let me that is like with working - **date_created** or **datecreated**