# convert date to milliseconds AngularJS javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I have a input in form like this:

```html
<input  id="sendDate" type="date" ng-model="aN.formData.sendDate" title="Formato inválido: introducir el número de segundos" required>
```

When i submit the form i have the output in console, this ouput: 
`Thu Oct 29 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)`

How I can convert this format to milliseconds when i send the form?

I've been reading other posts and have not been of much help.

thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925020/angularjs-convert-tag-value-unix-time-to-human-readable-time

Comment: Is your question answered?

Answer (score 10):

```
new Date('Thu Oct 29 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)').getTime()
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a date - not a period of time - so you can't convert that to milliseconds ...

Do you want to convert it to a unix timestamp ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime

Or do you want to get the milliseconds from a that time ?

```
var today = new Date();
var milliseconds = today.getMilliseconds();
```

example above from - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMilliseconds

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.aN.formData.sendDate.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try moment.js (http://momentjs.com/docs). There is an "duration" feature to get milliseconds, but there is a bunch of alternative ones you wrap a date into moment.js