# how to convert milliseconds from since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 to date 1/20/2016

Tags: c#, html, angularjs

{{}}
 is the tag i am using in my html.
when i get date from database it is showing Date(1453228200000) in milliseconds for date 1/20/2016.
how to solve it.

Comment: <input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="data.Last_recharge_date" /> is the tag

Comment: You should put your additional info in the question by editing it, I think

Comment: format your date at server to ISO string or Unix timestamp or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/format-a-microsoft-json-date/2316066#2316066

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var date = new Date(parseInt($scope.data.Last_recharge_date)); Before this you have to remove the substring "Date(" and ")" and pass only milliseconds number then only you will get. try to remove the string

Comment: this won't parse what OP is sending from server by itself

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925020/angularjs-convert-tag-value-unix-time-to-human-readable-time  check this here they answered same

Comment: inside {{item.date * 1000 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}  try to use like this

Comment: Do you referred what charlietfl given link ?

Comment: they used var date = new Date(parseInt(1453228200000));

Comment: var date = new Date(parseInt($scope.data.Last_recharge_date));  Before this you have to remove the substring "Date(" and ")" and pass only milliseconds number then only you will get. try to remove the string

Comment: thank's bro its working after parsing  and removing the Date and ()

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `new Date(1453228200000)` and then apply any filters/format filter you need

Comment: I did this in js                                                                                                 var date = new Date(parseInt($scope.data.Last_recharge_date));
        $scope.data.Last_recharge_date = date;

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways you can convert to the date format.

1. Create a custom filter. Add the code in custom filter 
   `new Date(1453228200000).toUTCString()` and It will return "Tue, 19 Jan 2016 18:30:00 GMT" .

   [Jsfiddle Custom Filter](https://jsfiddle.net/Nidhin/6d6yy9g8/1/)
2. Use the same code to convert to date format on the service level(after fetching data form server).

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display the milliseconds of a given date-time.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var d = new Date(1453228200000);
    var n = d.toString();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

There are lot of other functions which can be used http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp.